# Is the SF-inspired music produced by StoOdin101 in the 1990s still available somewhere?

Tags: music, instrumentality-of-mankind

Back in the 1990s, I was acquainted with a fellow whose username was StoOdin101.  He produced science-fiction-inspired electronic music, including works based on the writings of H. P. Lovecraft and (in accord with his name, which was taken from Cordwainer Smith's story "Under Old Earth") a piece entitled "Congohelium Conga" (inspired by the bizarre musical instrument that features in that story).

However, while there are relic references to the creator still out there on the World-Wide Web, I cannot find any of his music still around.  Having corresponded with him, back twenty years ago, I tried contacting him at his old AOL address a while back and did not get a response.  Does anybody know if this SF-inspired music is still preserved somewhere that is accessible?

Comment: Have you tried emailing him/her? [stoodin101@aol.com](http://www.angelfire.com/space2/pyrkium/Lovecraft/070_TSOU_The_Whisperer_in_Darkness.htm) was the address that they used on AOL boards

Comment: Is this the same guy? https://josephcurwen.bandcamp.com/

Comment: @Valorum Curwen isn't the same guy, but he looks interesting.

Comment: Maybe contact the webmaster [here](http://www.hplovecraft.com/internet/ahcfaq/about.aspx) where his email is listed, and see if they are willing to help locate? Maybe a mail to contributors?

Comment: Also found a russian email addy: stoodin101@rambler.ru

Comment: @JohnP I've e-mailed that address to see if it's him.  (It might or might not be; "sto odin" means "one hundred one" in Russian, and it's the name of a character from Cordwainer Smith's "Under Old Earth")